# Single path exclusion from find (pruning)

Tags: bash, find

Is there anyway to tell `/usr/bin/find` to blacklist a certain directory by absolute location. I'm using `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`.

```
find . -type f -not -path '*/media/*'
```

I would expect this never to traverse a through anything within a path named `/media/`. However, this clearly isn't the case. Reading the docs I see the answer is in `-prune`.

```
find . -path '*/media/*' -prune | grep media
```

However, that still returns stuff

```
./media/.listing
./media/ChromeImageGallery
./media/WheelsTV
./media/AutoBuilder4-Data
```

How come even with `-prune` find is returning stuff in the `/media/` subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
find . -path '*/media/*' -prune -o -print
```

It will output `media` but not anything under it.

The following will completely eliminate `media`:

```
find . -name 'media' -prune -o -print
```

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Note that for more complex expressions, you may need to group parts of them using `\(` and `\)`. See the `EXAMPLES` section of `man find` for more information.